# Produce Large Object file from Smaller source file

Tags: c++

I need to stress test my program with large object files. I have researched into C++ Templates and inline functions/templates but have not been able to get the desired obj/source size ratio I want (about 50). I want to be able to have a single source compiled to a single object file with the latter's max size of 200MB. Any high level ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Additional Edit: I have created large/complex and diverse (random) template functions and have started calling them (creating instantiations) with unique types/parameters. This increased the obj/source ratio, as expected, to a certain point (around 12). Then the ratio dropped significantly (about 1) to what I assume is gcc outsmarting me and optimizing my methods. I have also looked into forcing gcc to create all functions inline, but my tests haven't shown improvements on that yet either.

Using the preprocessor to code bloat is not a valid technique for what I wish to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the preprocessor to generate lots and lots of code at preprocessing, but that might count for you as the source file being large on its own.

Generally speaking, the machine code that a C++ compiler produces is relatively small (in bytes) compared to the code that wrote it.
One thing that does hog up space is string resources. Now, if you use the same string over and over again the compiler will be smart enough to realise that it only needs to store it once, but if you change the resource a little bit each time then each variation will probably be stored separately. This changing can be done using the preprocessor.

Another idea is like you said, using templates to generate lots of functions for a lot of different types.

What is it that you want to accomplish? There might be better ways.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to be able to use gcc to compile a single source file (C++) to produce a single object size about 30-50 times the size. I need to be able to generate .o files in the 100s of MB. In other words I want massive code bloat

Comment: @user3662606: Is using the preprocessor a valid method for you? In that case, I have edited my post with the general idea of using the preprocessor. Else, if it is not 'allowed', could you edit into your question what you have tried with templates, and why that didn't work? Perhaps the template code can be improved.

Comment: I have edited my question to be more specific. I though I had a good plan using unique instantiations of multiple unique templates, but then at around 40 calls (5 per 8 templates) the objective file size shrunk in half and killed my desire ratio. Thanks in advance